# Where is the type Unsubscribe coming from?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hi I am trying to return the state if the user is available or not inside the component.
What I am trying to do is `return true` if user logged in `else false`

I am using the method given by fire base to keep track of the user logged in state

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged
```

Here is my code for this.

```
const isLoggedIn = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    console.log(!!user)
    return !!user;
  });

  const showSaveTheProgressButton:boolean = isLoggedIn;
```

But when I try to return the boolean value from this method I am getting something else rather than boolean

```
Type 'false | Unsubscribe' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

Above is the error statement I am getting from the program.
From what I am understanding there the program shouldn't be returning `Unsubscribe` right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using `onAuthStateChanged` correctly.  It won't return the value that your return inside its callback.  It always returns immediately with an unsubscribe function, regardless of what the function does that you passed to it.  You're supposed to use the callback to take action on the state of the user whenever that  changes between signed in and signed out.

If you want the current user object immediately (if the there is a user signed in), then simply use `firebase.auth().currentUser`.  However, you should know that this will always return null immediately when the page loads.  You should use `onAuthStateChanged` to know when the user object first becomes available, fi that's what you're trying to know.